# How to extract 3 integers from "v%d.%d.%d" string format?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to extract 3 numbers out of the semantic version string which has the following format: `"v%d.%d.%d"`

Here's my example code:

```
std::string myVersion = "v3.49.1";
int versionMajor, versionMinor, versionPatch;
getVersionInfo(myVersion, versionMajor, versionMinor, versionPatch);
std::cout << versionMajor << " " << versionMinor << " " << versionPatch << '\n';
```

The expected result:

```
3 49 1
```

How can I design the function `getVersionInfo()`?

What would be the most elegant solution?

Comment: `std::scanf` is the most straight-forward option in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/):

```
void getVersionInfo(std::string version, int &major, int &minor, int &patch) {
    sscanf(version.c_str(), "v%d.%d.%d", &major, &minor, &patch);
}
```

[Try it here](http://cpp.sh/7yiyy)

Comment: `if (sscanf (...) != 3) { /* handle error */ }`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You can try this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s="v3.49.1";
    int major,minor,patch;
    int x=s.find(".");

    //We dont want v symbol so start from 1 till 1st dot
    major=stoi(s.substr(1,x));
    cout<<major;

    //Then find second dot from first symbol and copy as sub string
    int y=s.find(".",x+1);
    minor=stoi(s.substr(x+1,y-x));
    cout<<minor;

    //After that remaining string will be patch version
    patch=stoi(s.substr(y+1));
    cout<<patch;
    return 0;
}
```